# how to configure ivy to resolve dependecies of htmlunit

Tags: dependencies, ivy, htmlunit

Ivy can resolve dependencies of dependencies, the documentation says that one can use module configurations to tell ivy that a configuration depends on a given configuration of the dependency.

I want to use htmlunit in a project, in its [sourceforge page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html) dependency informations i found dependency settings i translated the maven specifications to ivy:

```
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" name="htmlunit" rev="2.11"/>
```

I wrote a test, compiled it, when tried to run it, i had a ClassNotFoundException, i went back again to sourceforge, and looked for informations about dependencies of htmlunit, in this [page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html) i found what i looked for, so i thought everything i need is using the magic of module configurations, so i added:

```
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" name="htmlunit" rev="2.11" conf="test->compile; test->test"/>
```

but i have this error telling me that the configuration was not found in net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.11, 'compile'

Answer (score 2):

The compile configuration does exist....

Attempting to reproduce your issue I discovered the following error message:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.11: 
    configuration not public in net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.11: 'test'......
```

When ivy translates a Maven module into configurations it does so in a manner that does not allow the resolution of transitive test dependencies.

There is some logic to this reasoning, after all the test dependencies are designed to support the testing of the htmlunit module. Your module should be explicitly declaring its own test dependencies....

What I'd normally suggest is to map your "test" configuration to the remote "runtime" Maven scope, in order to pick up additional jars:

```
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" 
            name="htmlunit" 
            rev="2.11" 
            conf="compile->default;test->runtime"/>
```

Problem is there are no "runtime" dependencies in the htmlunit module, meaning this won't be any help.

In conclusion, you have not indicated which class was missing. If it's something obvious like junit then I'd suggest this is something that should be explicitly declared in your ivy file.